# Can't implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EmployeeInfo.Models.Employee>'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get data from MVC controller in anonymous type using angularjs. But here is a problem in getting this way and show compile time error. How to I write the code?
ASP.Net MVC,

```
  public JsonResult Get_AllEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeeInfoContext Obj = new EmployeeInfoContext())
        {
            List<Employee> Emp = Obj.Employees.Select(e => new {
                EmpId=e.EmpId,
                EmpName = e.EmpName,
                DeptId = e.DeptId,
                CityId = e.CityId
            }).ToList();
            return Json(Emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As the error suggests, `Emp` is defined as a list of `Employee`, but you try to put an anonymous type (`new {}`) in there. You either need to change the declaration of `Emp` (and use implicit typing, because you use an anonymous type) or you need to actually map it to `Employee` instead.

Comment: An anonymous type can never be equal to a concrete type. Use either all anonymous or all concrete, not both.

Answer (score 3):

You either 1. don't need the anonymous type or 2. shouldn't try to assign it to the type it isnt.

1.

```
public JsonResult Get_AllEmployee()
{
    using (EmployeeInfoContext Obj = new EmployeeInfoContext())
    {
        List<Employee> Emp = Obj.Employees.ToList();
        return Json(Emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and 2.

```
public JsonResult Get_AllEmployee()
{
    using (EmployeeInfoContext Obj = new EmployeeInfoContext())
    {
        var Emp = Obj.Employees.Select(e => new {   //notice var here
            EmpId=e.EmpId,
            EmpName = e.EmpName,
            DeptId = e.DeptId,
            CityId = e.CityId
        }).ToList();

        return Json(Emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```